# Double Nested JSON to DF

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm unable to make this JSON:

```
{

“profiles”: {

    “1”: {

        “id”: “1”,

        “property1”: “value1”,

        “property2”: “value2”

    },

    “2”: {

        “id”: “2”,

        “property1”: “value21”,

        “property2”: “value22”

    }

}}
```

To this format
Desired output

```
Id            Property1            Property2

1              Value1                  Value2

2              Value21                Value22
```

I've attempted different approaches, that just result in one col all data.
Can someone please orient me on this?

Comment: Can you please add what approaches you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this example:

```
data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

     col_1 col_2
0      3     a
1      2     b
2      1     c
3      0     d
```

I would suggest something like:

```
your_json = {<your_json>}

property1 = []
property2 = []
for key, value in your_json.items():
    for k, v in value.items():
        property1.append(v['property1'])
        property2.append(v['property2'])

data = {'property1': property1, 'property2': property2}
tt = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

print(tt)
```